# Best way to update files on production server from development server

Tags: server, apt, package-management, application-development

I am developing a website for my own company. To do so I have 2 servers:

- Server 1: a development server where I upload and test files. I use Adobe Dreamweaver CS6 to put and get files I am working on; I myself work on MAC OS;
- Server 2: a production server where accepted files are put into production

Both servers run Ubuntu 14.04.

I recently looked into creating a debian package on the development server. I followed [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) guide to create one. It seemed to go well and all except that I don't want my package to be grabbed by everyone on the internet by putting it on the Ubuntu public package archive.

This package should contain all the php/javascript/stylesheet files I created and tested on Server 1. On the production server (Server 2) I was hoping on the possibility to **apt-get install my-package-name** once a new feature on Server 1 is fully tested and accepted. I understand that this is only possible with packages uploaded to the Ubuntu archive.

My question therefor is: it possible to create a private archive/repository so that I can **apt-get install** my package on the production server from the development server? Or is there a different and/or better way to update the files on the production server after testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create your own apt repository and configure your production server ot use it. You do NOT need to post your debs in a public ppa (i.e., Ubuntu archive).

This [wki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal) gives you the basic steps to create a deb repository and how to update it when you put new versions of packages in it.

The guide is about creating a local, disk-based repository. In your case I would guess you want to make it available for remote consumption - you can do that by just exposing the directory in apache2.

Comment: Can I ask for an example on how someone would expose that directory in apache2?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a something like git. That way you can have separate branches for production and development, once you are happy, merge the development branch in to production, and then git pull

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into git as well. But it costs a few bucks to have a private repository.

Comment: You need to look harder then. You can host your own repositories, as well as using somebody else to do it for you. Bitbucket will host a private git repository for you for free